# Rails and signature pad from Thomas J Bradley

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, signature

im using rails + jquerymobile + signature pad (http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/)

my problem is to Converting to an Image(http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/#images)

when im drawing the signature and submit the form, i get some weird errors:

```
convert.exe: Non-conforming drawing primitive definition `line' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3154.
convert.exe: unable to open image `111,9': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2641.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `111,9' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/550.
```

code in my controller.rb:

```
  instructions = JSON.load(params[:output]).map { |h| "line #{h['mx']},#{h['my']} #{h['lx']},#{h['ly']}" } * ' '
  system "convert -size 198x55 xc:transparent -stroke blue -draw '#{instructions}' signature.png"
```

https://gist.github.com/branch14/4258871

any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling imagemagick.

`brew uninstall imagemagick`

or 

`brew remove imagemagick`
.

Then,

`brew install imagemagick`